# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'detect_nonsilent'

Tags: python, list, while-loop, pydub

Running this snippet of code:

```
while True:
    print('recording')
    myrecording = sd.rec(int(seconds * fs), samplerate=fs, channels=1, dtype=np.int16)
    sd.wait()  # Wait until recording is finished
    write('output.wav', fs, myrecording.astype(np.int16))
    sound = AudioSegment.from_file("output.wav", format="wav")
    lsound = sound + 35

    silence = silence.detect_nonsilent(lsound, min_silence_len=1000, silence_thresh=-15)

    silence = [((start/1000),(stop/1000)) for start,stop in silence] #convert to sec
    print(silence)
    print(len(silence))
    if len(silence) == 0:
        print('silence')
    else:
        print('have recording')
        lsound.export("loutput.wav", format='wav')
```

During first iteration every thing works fine

```
recording
[(0.0, 0.502), (1.842, 5.0)]
2
have recording
```

But during next iteration get:

```
recording
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sttgft.py", line 43, in <module>
    silence = silence.detect_nonsilent(lsound, min_silence_len=1000, silence_thresh=-15)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'detect_nonsilent'
```

Attempted to delete 'silence' with del silence command but then get;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sttgf1.py", line 43, in <module>
    silence = silence.detect_nonsilent(lsound, min_silence_len=1000, silence_thresh=-15)
NameError: name 'silence' is not defined
```

Don't know what to try

Comment: After the first iteration of your `while` loop this line `silence = [((start/...` will have made `silence` a `list` therefore `silence.detect_nonsilent(` will not work for the reason your traceback mentioned

Answer (score 0):

1. If you delete silence then the line of code below will throw an error as to get the final `silence`, it must be already there.

`silence = silence.detect_nonsilent(lsound, min_silence_len=1000, silence_thresh=-15)`

2. Now check what is the value of `silence` before while loop, because once it completes the first iteration `silence` becomes a list datatype and the same line of code mentioned above will do a `list.detect_nonsilent`. That is why you are getting the first error after first iteration.

Comment: Understand. Is there a way of getting around this?

Comment: please mention the datatype of silence that is given before while loop, and what does this `detect_nonsilent` expect

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake. Using the name 'silence' in 'silence = silence.detect_nonsilent...'
caused the error. once I changed to "silenc = silence.detect_nonsilent..." it worked perfectly.